# How do i split into a block of 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to separate a set of 3 numbers with a comma and set the value to a textarea, i have tried this but it just brings the values concatenated like this "5.685.685.85", i want it to appear like this "5.68, 5.68, 5.85"

```
var once = window['tma'+kj].toFixed(2);
for (var li=0; li<once.length; ++li) {
    $('#comments').append(once[li]); //div tag, it shows concateneted
    $('#com').val(once[li]); //textarea id, brings blank
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about your use of the 'once' variable - toFixed will return a String, but you are looping over it as though it was an array, do you want to iterate over each character in the String?

Comment: What do you get from `console.log (typeof once);'? Is it an array, or a string?

Comment: console.log returns values horizontally continuously, if i remove .toFixed(2) it returns nothing. I was using to fixed remove extra dighits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var once = window['tma'+kj];
var arr = [];
for (var li=0; li<once.length; ++li) {
    $('#comments').append(once[li]); //div tag, it shows concateneted
    arr.push(once[li].toFixed(2)); //textarea id, brings blank
}
$('#com').val(arr.join(','));
```

Comment: your suggestion returns this "5,.,8,5" what could be the reason?

Comment: window['tma'+kj] is individual computed values of input boxes that i have

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `once` is an array:

```
$('#comments').val(once.join (', '))
```

Comment: once is a String from the look of the code provided, although it is being treated as though it was an array

Comment: That's what confuses me. I suppose I should've asked for clarification as regards that point... =/

Comment: once is an array variable holding the values of textboxes

Comment: @alpho07 - in the code shown above 'once' is a string (not an array), you can verify this as suggested by David above, by using console.log

Comment: It brings back TypeError: once.join is not a function

Comment: Then something else is going on that we can't see. Verify that `once` is an array, and produce a live ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) demo that reproduces your problem. Then we can see what's going on, and try to help.